# C program strings

Tags: c, string, debugging

For part of my program I would like to concatenate two strings together with an asterisk  between each character. For example, if I had a first string of `"abcde"` and a second string of `"1234567"`, I would like to have a result of  `"a*b*c*d*e*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*"`.

For this part of the program I have:

```
char *widen_stars(char *one, char *two)
{

    int length_one = strlength(one); // length of first parameter
    int length_two = strlength(two); // Length of second parameter

    char *p = malloc((sizeof(char) * (length_one + length_two) * 2)+ 1), *p_start; //Allocate enough memory for both strings concatenated together with a * between each letter

    p_start = p;

        while(*one != '0') 
        {
            if( (p - p_start) % 2 == 0) // Keeps track of where we are in the p string
            {
            *p = *one;
            p++;
            one++;
            }
            else
            {
            *p = '*';
            p++;
            }
        }



        while(*two != '0')
        {
            if( (p - p_start) % 2 == 0)
            {
            *p = *two;
            p++;
            two++;
            }
            else
            {
            *p = '*';
            p++;
            }
        }



return p_start;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char first[31]= {0};
    char second[31]= {0};
    char *f = first, *s = second;

    printf("Please enter a string of maximum 30 characters: ");
    scanf("%s", f);
    printf("Please enter a string of maximum 30 characters: ");
    scanf("%s", s);

    printf("The combined string is: %s\n", widen_stars(f, s));

    }
return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the program with the above inputs, I get something like `"a*b*c*d*e*"`, without any of the second string. If I block out the first while loop into comments to test the second loop, I get something like `"1*2*3*4*5*5*7*"`, which leaves me scratching my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is in `while` conditions, you should increment pointers until `'\0'` not `'0'`. So instead of doing:

```
while(*one != '0')
...
while(*two != '0')
```

You do it like this:

```
while(*one != '\0')
...
while(*two != '\0')
```

And as you are returning a dynamically allocated memory, consider using a pointer to this memory, which you `free` after usage:

```
char *str = widen_stars(f, s);
printf("The combined string is: %s\n", str);
free(str);
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, I didn't realize how important the "\" is, and thank you for the other tip, I have just started learning about dynamically allocated memory :)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem lies here:

```
while(*oneOrTwo != '0')
```

If you're looking for the end of the strings, it's `'\0'` that you should be looking for, not `'0'`. The former is the end-of-string marker, the latter is simply the *character* `0`.

---

And, as an aside, there are much less ..., err,  *verbose* ways to do this (assuming it's not class work - if it is, you should go with your current method). For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *widen_stars(char *one, char *two) {
    // Need to cater for memory exhaustion.

    char *p = malloc((strlen(one) + strlen(two)) * 2) + 1);
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;

    // Init to empty string in case both inputs empty.

    *p = '\0';

    // Save string start for return.

    char *p_start = p;

    // Add character and asterisk for every character in both strings.

    while (*one != '\0') {
        sprintf(p, "%c*", *one++);
        p += 2;
    }

    while (*two != '\0') {
        sprintf(p, "%c*", *two++);
        p += 2;
    }

    // Remove last asterisk (if needed).

    // *(--p) = '\0';

    // Return result.

    return p_start;
}
```

That's based on your actual expected results, which place an asterisk *after* each character. However, your specifications call for an asterisk *between* each character. If you decide to got for the latter, it's a simple matter of un-commenting the penultimate statement in the function, to basically back up and replace the final asterisk with an end-of-string marker.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize the importance of the "\"

Comment: Yes it's for class work and had to be done a certain way, but I appreciate your code too. I'm very new to coding and I'm always interested in improving efficiency in whatever I code.